# Update Salesforce records from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, salesforce, soql

I have installed the Cloud Connector script from:
http://www.sanjaygidwani.net/2011/09/10/how-to-setup-and-run-cloudconnector/

I can successfully query salesforce data.

My question is how to update records. I come from Microsoft Access, VBA, and SQL.

In SQL, I would just use this:

```html
UPDATE Prospect__c SET Prospect__c.Field1__c = "ABC123"
WHERE Prospect__c.Id = “AAA";
```

How would I accomplish this with SOQL or any other way from Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, I found out that SOQL cannot update records and that I will need to try another method, such as http patch.